# Windows 2012: how to make power button work in every cases?

Tags: windows-server-2012, shutdown

I need some Windows 2012 servers to be shutdown properly with the power button.

- If nobody is logged, the power button correctly shuts down the server
- If somebody is logged without a blocking program, it's okay too

But:

- if a session is locked, the power button does nothing
- if somebody is logged with a blocking program (notepad with an unsaved document for example), the button does nothing too

With previous Windows versions I was used to configure the power button behaviour with the GUI and modify a registry key (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\policies\system\shutdownwithoutlogon`) but this seems not any more relevant.

Does anyone knows the "offical" way, or a trick ?

Edit:
The system log display an event each time I press the power button. `The kernel power manager has initiated a shutdown transition` with event ID 109.
When the session is locked, this event is followed by nothing. And no other events in other logs.
When a program refuse to close, I have the corresponding log entry, so this will be okay soon.

Comment: Show those damn smart switches who's really smart: yank the F^&%#ing power cord out of the wall!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fact you can't power down a 2012 server when a session is locked is probably by design. I faced a similar need and don't know any policy or registry change to allow that.

I used a simple trick: I captured the power button event which simply run my favorite shutdown.exe with the desired parameters after a timeout.
If you use the correct shutdown parameters, you won't be blocked by open programs.

To capture events, just open the task scheduler and create a task triggered on the desired event ID.

Comment: For reference, the command I use is: shutdown /s /t 10 /d p:0:0

Comment: Also for reference the event in my case is a basic event with these properties Log: System, Source: Kernel-Power, Event-ID: 109

Answer (score 1):

Check out [AutoEndTasks](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc736867%28v=ws.10%29.aspx):

You can set it for all users by creating the key here vs HKCU:
HKEY_USERS.DEFAULT\Control Panel\Desktop

Additionally, there is some tuning that can be done via group policy that can be found here:
Computer Configuration>Administrative Templates>System>Shutdown Options>
[Turn off automatic termination of applications that block or cancel shutdown](http://gpsearch.azurewebsites.net/default.aspx?ref=1#2813)

Additional tuning options that you may want to look into are:
[WaitToKillServiceTimeout](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc976045.aspx),[WaitToKillAppTimeout](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc978624.aspx),[HungAppTimeOut](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc978614.aspx)

I'll also second what MarcoZink stated, check your Bios and verify there isn't any special setting configured for your power button that may be holding things up.

Comment: I would not second what MarcoZink stated about the BIOS because the question clearly states "If nobody is logged, the power button correctly shuts down the server"